# What's the right procedure to promote a proposed synonym?

Tags: discussion, voting, tags

```
Users with a total answer score of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms.
```

Where's the right place to let people know that there's a new synonym up for a vote?

Answer (score 1):

meta?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, nobody else had posted one; I figured that someone else would have done so before me. Just put it up as a question, then, and hope people notice?

Comment: Search on "synonym," there's a bunch of questions, though sometimes it comes out of other synonym related discussion. http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/669/proposed-tag-synonyms